# CSS style working in Chrome/FF but not applying in IE8

Tags: css, stylesheet

I inherited a site that I'm working on finishing and there is this style applied to  tags inside my footer (forgive me if I don't give enough info, just let me know and I'll put it up).  The style puts a subtle background color around the header text and rounds the corners a bit:

```
    h4 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(32, 37, 41, 0.3);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    color: #5CB414;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px 0 8px 10px;
    position: relative;
    }
```

This works great in Chrome and FF but in IE8 it doesn't work.  And in IE8 it doesn't float the columns next to each other.  [Here is the site.](http://www.solarrenewablepowersystems.com.php5-8.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/)  Scroll down to the bottom to see the issues (should be 3 columns but in IE it is only 2 and there is no background style applied to the H4.

I know IE is finicky, but I don't know what to do about it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of IE prior to 9 don't support RGBA or border radius, so these are simply being ignored. You can try the cross-browser syntax at http://css3please.com, but this won't give you rounded corners in versions of IE prior to 9.

Your column float issue stems from the use of an nth-child selector on line 1454 of your style.css:

.col:nth-child(3) { margin-right: 0; }

Again, IE8 and lower don't support this so you'll have to find a work around. You can add a class of "last" to the third column, and place this in your stylesheet:

col.last { margin-right: 0 !important; }

Comment: I believe it's not actually supported in IE8 either.

Comment: You're right, it's not. I always get confused because I use "first-child" most of the time for this very reason, since it's supported in IE7+ and simply fix it in IE6 if I need to. Answer edited with the bulletproof fix.

Comment: Is that suppose to be `.col.last` ?  I know you can add multiple classes to an element but that has me a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: Ok it worked with .col.last and I got the color fixed with the `filter` property in everything <= IE8.  It's been a while since I've gotten this deep into CSS, is it really this dirty between browsers?? :)

Answer (score 2):

as far as losing the 3 columns at the bottom simple replace the ".col" `width:300px` to `width:292px;` It's just barely too big.

Also with the rounded corners being crossbrowser compatible I like to get my styles from here: http://css3please.com/

I do not know that rounded corners will work in ie8 or less so you might try doing it with jquery instead of css3
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: Thank you this was helpful but I didn't want to change the width of my columns so I used amustill's suggestion by adding a .last class to the column.  I wish I could give you both the answer check! Thanks!